# jQuery UI - draggable object slower than mousemove || $(window).scrollTop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

*I am not sure if I'm allowed to ask 2 questions at the same time. Tell me if I shouldn't do that in future.*
So:

1. I got a draggable object (done with jQuery UI) and when I drag it, it's way slower than I move my mouse. You can check it out [**here**](https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/GEmBNE). Just drag the black, semi-transparent rectangle at the top right a bit down to see the effect.
2. On the same codepen, I got another problem. If I drag that rectangle, the page should scroll down. I tried to do that with the following code:

   ```
   $(".draggable").draggable({
     drag: function() {
       var dragTop = $(".draggable").css('top');
       $(window).scrollTop(
         $(document).scrollTop() + dragTop
       );
     },
     containment: ".scrollIndicator", 
     axis: "y",
   });
   ```

   So I get the CSS `top` of the draggable object. And then I made a simple `$(window).scrollTop();` to scrolldown on the page, with an offset of the `top` property of the object.

Anyone knows what I did wrong or how I can fix that?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This is slow due to the transform property on the `.scrollIndicator` element.

Comment: @NathanP. Thanks, now I know why it's not working properly at all. Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: No, that's why I didn't made it an answer, I can't think of a correct solution right now. Maybe reduce it's size using height/width css properties. Anyway, let me know if you find out :).

Comment: @NathanP. I solved it by playing the `.draggable` out of the `.scrollIndicator` container. Now other problems appear tho :D